# Can't reach iis server via external ip

Tags: ip, windows-server-2012, localhost, iis-8

I am using aws from amazon and I have iis intalled on my server. I have created a test site but I can't reach it using external ip address. It is only reachable throught http://localhost- and 10.0.241.77 the local ip. How can I make iis run on external ip?

Comment: 10.0.241.77 **is** its internal IP. Which IP are you referring to?

Comment: Internal ip is 54.93.xx.xxx but iis uses 10.0.241.77 I am really confused

Comment: 54.93.xx.xxx is its external IP, not internal. Have you configured your AWS security group to make port 80 available to 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: Sorry it is my fault I am not a native speaker. I'm not the owner of the aws account. I just have the external ip of server and admin account

Comment: It's most likely a misconfigured security group.

Comment: What should I do then? I may try to call the account owner tomorrow.

Comment: I got port:80 opened fron AWS options, and it works fine now. If you write your suggestion as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments, AWS security groups needed to be set up to allow public access to port 80.